# Expected expression before error

Tags: c, struct, expression

I've been working on this project for a while and I wanted to test it, but I keep getting this error and I have no idea what to do and I am very confused. Here is my code:

```
    typedef struct{
       int nr_pages;
       int id;
       int a,b; 
       int aux;
    }information;

    int main(){
     int i;
     i = information.b;
     //and more stuff happens
    }
```

The error that I am always getting is "Expected expression before 'information'" exactly where I declare i = information.b
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If your intention was to have a global *variable* named `information`, then drop the keyword `typedef` from your code. Otherwise you're declaring a *type*, not a variable.

Answer (score 4):

You need to instantiate the structure before using it. Try:

```
typedef struct{
   int nr_pages;
   int id;
   int a,b; 
   int aux;
}information;

int main(){

 information info;
 info.b = 0;
 info.a = 0;
 ...
 etc
 ...

 int i = information.b;
 //and more stuff happens
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You declare `information` as a type, not a variable. This is what the `typedef` is for.

And `i = ...` in the C terminology is not a declaration, but an assignment.